# How to make a Task execute in interval?

Tags: java, android

I have a for loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<payloadList.size(); i++){
    .....
}
```

and a boolean variable "resultOk". I would like each one in for loop, it will do in 5s (timeout). If in 5s, "resultOk" is true, it will move to next in for loop. If the time is up, it will break for loop.
Could you give me some suggestion? How to do? Thank you!

Comment: Use thread/handler or Timer

Comment: Hi S S K, Could you give me some details about your suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this example (I don't know what you want to do at each situation):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
    for (Callable<Boolean> payload : payloadList) {
        Future<Boolean> result = executorService.submit(payload);
        try {
            if (!result.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
                System.out.println("result was false");
                break;
            }
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            System.out.println("ran into a timeout");
            result.cancel(true);
            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("something went wrong");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** you have to close the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) afterwards using `shutdownNow()` or  `shutdown()`. Best way to do that is in a `try {} finally {}` statement, which I omitted to keep the code small and simple.

Comment: Hi Harmlezz, in each situation, i do some works and i want they run in timeout is 5s.

Comment: Do you want each of them to run for 5 seconds, regardless of the result of each? As of your question, the loop will break when the 5 seconds are exceeded, the result is false or an exception is thrown. It is up to you to handle the situations differently. Just change the **breaks** to something you like to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < payloadList.size(); i++){
   try{       
      Thread.sleep(5000);// Wait 5 secs
      if(playloadList.size().get(i).IsResultOk()){
         continue; // If result of element of playloadList is ok go to next index
      }
      break; // stop for because result of element is not ok
   }catch(InterruptedException cantWait){
      break; // stop for because the thread couldnt wait the 5 secs
   }
}
```

If you do it like this, you have to wait every time in the loop for 5 secs, before the next element is on turn. if you dont want this tell me and i ll make a second example which wont wait the whole time

Comment: Hi Basti, i don't want wait for 5 secs in each. 5s is timeout. The for loop will be break if timeout is up, it will continue if while 5s, the variable "resultOk" is true.

Comment: okay. initialize a counter with 0, put the sleep down to 1 and put the sleep in a while, which is running as long as your counter is < 5000. every time in your while after the sleep you set your counter 1 up. but in before all of this, over the sleep but in the while, you check for you boolean. if(true)break; you ll have to set a flag or make a own method to break the for afterwards. shall i code that or did you understand? this is how to make a timeout on his own

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
   int i = 0;
   @Override
   public void run() {
      if(i < payloadList.size()) {
         // do stuff
         if(++i < payloadList.size()) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
         }
      }
   }
}
handler.post(task);
```

You'll need to ensure that payloadList is not modified while this is working.